# Rookie question about ne Blender 2.75a rotating view

Tags: interface, 3d-view

I just upgraded from 2.72b to 2.75a and now I can't rotate my view with my mouse anymore. Even if i hold down the shift button, it wont change my view either. I have tried changing the free/trackball option in User Preferences, but it doesn't do anything. Any advise?

Comment: That's very strange.. Does enabling *Emulate 3 button mouse* and using Alt+LMB instead of MMB do anything?

Comment: doesnt appear to do anything

Comment: Hm. Have you tried reverting to factory settings?

Comment: Yes sir, ive tried that several times. I will re'install it all, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Got it working now, and followed your advice for the Alt+LMB - it works! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Well, MMB  *should* work, unless there is something wrong with the middle mouse button on your mouse. If MMB still doesn't work but Alt LMB does, you might want to try it with a different mouse.